# Flashair issue with LUA_SD_EVENT (Files are not transfering using FTP)

Tags: events, lua, ftp, wifi, flashair

The ftpupload.lua file is not running or there is issue in the code. I need it for my FlashAir Wi-fi sdcard.

I used this code before:

```
require("Settings")

local ftpstring = "ftp://"..user..":"..passwd.."@"..server.."/"..serverDir.."/"
local lockdir = "/uploaded/"   -- trailing slash required, and folder must already exist

function exists(path)
    if lfs.attributes(path) then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

function is_uploaded(path)
    local hash = fa.hash("md5", path, "")
    return exists(lockdir .. hash)
end

function set_uploaded(path)
    local hash = fa.hash("md5", path, "")
    local file = io.open(lockdir .. hash, "w")
    file:close()
end

function delete(path)
    -- Both of the following methods cause the next photo to be lost / not stored.
    fa.remove(path)
    -- fa.request("http://127.0.0.1/upload.cgi?DEL="..path)
end

function upload_file(folder, file)
    local path = folder .. "/" .. file
    -- Open the log file
    local outfile = io.open(logfile, "a")
    outfile:write(file .. " ... ")
    local response = fa.ftp("put", ftpstring..file, path)

    --Check to see if it worked, and log the result!
    if response ~= nil then
        print("Success!")
        outfile:write(" Success!\n")
        set_uploaded(path)
        if delete_after_upload == true then
            print("Deleting " .. file)
            outfile:write("Deleting " .. file .. "\n")
            sleep(1000)
            delete(path)
            sleep(1000)
        end
    else
        print(" Fail ")
        outfile:write(" Fail\n")
    end
    --Close our log file
    outfile:close()
end

function walk_directory(folder)
    -- Recursively iterate filesystem
    for file in lfs.dir(folder) do
        local path = folder .. "/" .. file
        local attr = lfs.attributes(path)
        print( "Found "..attr.mode..": " .. path )

        if attr.mode == "file" then
            if not is_uploaded(path) then
                upload_file(folder, file)
            else
                print(path .. " previously uploaded, skipping")
            end
        elseif attr.mode == "directory" then
            print("Entering " .. path)
            walk_directory(path)
        end
    end
end

-- wait for wifi to connect
while string.sub(fa.ReadStatusReg(),13,13) ~= "a" do
    print("Wifi not connected. Waiting...")
    sleep(1000)
end
walk_directory(folder)
```

But then i found a tutorial where was little bit different code, so i decided to use it:

```
--[[
FTPUpload.lua
Copyright (c) 2019 Toshiba Memory Corporation.
All sample code on this page is licensed under BSD 2-Clause License
https://github.com/FlashAirDevelopers/LuaTutorial/blob/master/LICENSE
]]

local logfile   = "/FTPLog.txt"     -- Log file created in FlashAir
local folder    = "/DCIM"         -- Folder to upload file is located
local server    = "192.168.50.178"     -- IP address of FTP server
local serverDir = "/home/andrexserver"    -- FTP server upload folder
local user      = "andrexserver"             -- FTP user name
local passwd    = "********"          -- FTP password

-- Assemble our FTP command string
-- example: "ftp://user:pass@192.168.1.1/LuaTutorial"
local ftpstring = "ftp://"..user..":"..passwd.."@"..server..serverDir

-- Open the log file
local outfile = io.open(logfile, "w")

-- Write a header
outfile:write("File list: \n")

-- For each file in folder...
for file in lfs.dir(folder) do
    -- Get that file's attributes
    attr = lfs.attributes(folder .. "/" .. file)
    print( "Found "..attr.mode..": " .. file )

    -- Don't worry about directories (yet)
    if attr.mode == "file" then
        --Attempt to upload the file!
        --ex ftp("put", "ftp://user:pass@192.168.1.1/LuaTutorial/test.jpg", "Upload/test.jpg")
        response = fa.ftp("put", ftpstring .. "/" .. file, folder .. "/" .. file)

        --Check to see if it worked, and log the result!
        if response ~= nil then
            print("Success!")
            outfile:write("" .. file .. "... Success!\n")
        else
            print("Fail :(")
            outfile:write("" .. file .. "... Fail :(\n")
        end
    end
end

--Close our log file
outfile:close()
```

But it still dont work
There's my CONFIG File:

```
[Vendor]

CIPATH=/DCIM/100__TSB/FA000001.JPG
VERSION=F15DBW3BW4.00.04
PRODUCT=FlashAir
VENDOR=TOSHIBA
APPMODE=5
APPSSID=KBELY 2G
APPNETWORKKEY=*********
DELCGI=/thumbnail.cgi,/config.cgi
APPNAME=WI-FI SD-CARD
UPLOAD=1
WEBDAV=0

MASTERCODE=accf856bbe74
LOCK=1

UPLOAD=1
STA_RETRY_CT=0
LUA_SD_EVENT=/ftpupload.lua
```

There is the tutorial codes on github: https://github.com/FlashAirDevelopers/LuaTutorial
Code that i used: https://github.com/FlashAirDevelopers/LuaTutorial/blob/master/lua_tutorial_4/FTPUpload.lua
I really dont know what to do.